# View dont render outside of ViewGroup bounds if ViewGroup alpha is inferior to 1

Tags: android

I just discovered that if a ViewGroup has clipChildren to false, views can rendered outside of its bounds only if this ViewGroup's alpha is set to 1. If I put any transparency on this ViewGroup, nothing can be rendered outside of its bound but I need to, is it a bug from ViewGroup?

Here is a simple test

```
private fun launchTest() {
        val viewGroup = FrameLayout(binding.content.context).also {
            binding.content.addView(it)
            it.updateLayoutParams {
                width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            }
            it.clipChildren = false
            it.clipToPadding = false
            it.pivotX = 0f
            it.pivotY = 0f
            it.translationX = 500f
            it.translationY = 500f
            it.background = ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW)

            //This prevents the view to render
            it.alpha = 0.5f
        }
        ImageView(viewGroup.context).also {
            viewGroup.addView(it)
            it.setImageDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.RED))
            it.updateLayoutParams {
                width = 128
                height = 128
            }
            it.translationX = -100f
            it.translationY = -100f
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know if I'd call it a bug, but it is a side-effect of how the draw routine has to handle any `View` with a non-opaque alpha. That `FrameLayout` has to be drawn into a separate, "off-screen" buffer, so that essentially clips its children to its bounds. `View`s in general aren't really set up to do any heavy drawing outside of their bounds. Those clip options in `ViewGroup` are mainly for edge effects and such, not for drawing something completely out of place. I'm not sure what your ultimate goal is, but maybe adding your `ImageView` to `binding.content`'s overlay instead would help.

Comment: @MikeM. I needed this feature for a graphic framework but I'll figure another way out to achieve my goal then